# K8s ANY load balancing?

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing

I have been getting more and more into k8s and I am trying some stuff on a personal VPS I have.
I have created a Deployment of a POD that uses another Service internally.
I would love to validate that these two services are being somewhat loadbalanced.

Here was my attempt to create this:
I have a simple service which I called **metric-test** which only has one endpoint that counts how many times it was called, logs it and returns this information.
For this I used the microframework **jooby** since I had familiarity with it and could get a fast start.

The code of this simple app can be [found on github](https://github.com/Flavsditz/k8s-balance-test)

Also on the repository I have added the **deployment.yaml** file with which I use to push it to my local version of **minikube** (which simulates my k8s env).

Steps taken:

1. Use this cmd to compile docker image into minikube repo: `eval $(minikube docker-env)`
2. I now build the project's docker image with `docker build . -t metric-test1`
3. I then apply the deployment file with `kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml` (the file is also on the github link

This gives me a Service of type **ClusterIP** (which is what I want since it should not be accessible from outside) and 2 PODS containing the jooby code. Here is the `deployment.yaml` file:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: metric-test
  labels:
    run: metric-test
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 3000
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    run: metric-test

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: metric-test
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 2
  revisionHistoryLimit: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: metric-test
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 0
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: metric-test
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: metric-test1
          imagePullPolicy: Never
          name: data-api
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000
              protocol: TCP
              name: 3000tcp
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
```

Alright everything working! I just set up a port-forwarding so I can access the service:
`kubectl port-forward service/metric-test 3000:3000`

And use this script to fire a lot of requests at the service:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
target=${1:-http://localhost:3000}
while true # loop forever, until ctrl+c pressed.
do
        for i in $(seq 100) # perfrom the inner command 100 times.
        do
                curl $target > /dev/null & # send out a curl request, the & indicates not to wait for the response.
        done

        wait # after 100 requests are sent out, wait for their processes to finish before the next iteration.
done
```

I am now seeing **ALL** of the requests being handled by only one of the pods while the other is just sitting there idle.

I went through the documentation ([here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types)) but to be honest I came out actually with more questions than answers. That is why I tried to create a simplified scenario to test these things out.

**Questions**

1. Can anyone help me out?
2. What am I missing? How can I achieve this load-balancing without exposing the service through the internet. I just want it to be available for other pods in the cluster.
3. (Bonus) The front-end services that are being served by an Ingress should all be properly load-balanced (right?)

Note: As far as I understood using `LoadBalancer` and `Ingress` you can actually achieve load-balancing, however, it also exposes to the outside.

### **EDIT 1**

More info on the deployment:
Result of `kubectl get po`

```
NAME                          READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
metric-test-f89bfbf86-ccrj8   1/1     Running   0          16h
metric-test-f89bfbf86-kl7qg   1/1     Running   0          16h
```

Here is a picture of the logs of both after running the curl script for a bit:
[image: Logs of both PODS]

### **EDIT FOR SOLUTION**

As m303945 said, the load balancing doesn't work out when we are using the port-forwarding.

In order to validate this, and any future tests I might want to do I did the following:

I've ran the following command in my terminal:

```
kubectl run -it --rm --restart=Never --image=alpine handytools -n ${1:-default} -- /bin/ash
```

which creates an alpine-based container and gives me shell access. At that point however, I cannot use curl since it is not installed. So for that I ran:

- `apk update`
- `apk add curl`

once I had that I've modified my previous bash script from above to run on this pod and try to hit the service I set up:

```sh
#!/bin/ash
target=${1:-http://metric-test:3000}
for i in $(seq 5) # loop 5 times to generate 500 calls.
do
        for i in $(seq 100) # perfrom the inner command 100 times.
        do
                curl $target > /dev/null & # send out a curl request, the & indicates not to wait for the response.
        done

        wait # after 100 requests are sent out, wait for their processes to finish before the next iteration.
done
```

The modifications included pointing to the service instead of the "localhost" and no port is needed. Also the alpine uses the `ash` and not the `bash` shell. I also ran 500 requests instead of infinity.

As you can see, running the above (which you can create using `vi` in alpine) I get a nice even load distribution!!!
[image: even distribution of calls]

Thanks again for user m303945 for pointing me in the right direction

Comment: The service you have should load balance very evenly among your 2 replicas. Are the replicas both up and Ready? Please share output of `kubectl get po`

Comment: By default, kube-proxy in iptables mode chooses a backend at random round-robin fashion so internally clusterIP is fine for that. How do you know that only one pod answers all the requests?

Comment: I will edit my question to add the answers to these. But yes both are up and running and I even have the logs showing that only one of them is being called (will post the pic too).
I can see that only one is answering due to the fact that I also added logging of each request.

Comment: Just curious, have you tried deleting one of the pods while the requests are going? Maybe see if the other receives traffic when the other replica gets deleted?

Comment: If I remember correctly, TCP load balancing was not working when using port forwarding. Can you try to run the script from a container inside k8s instead of doing port forwarding?

Comment: Will try both and get back to everyone.

Comment: If I deleted the pods while the requests were happening the pods would get recreated but were not picking up the previous requests (which is weird).

Comment: However, by creating a POD inside the cluster where I can test (used an alpine image) the calling of the other services than indeed  it worked! Thanks @m303945 you magic-question-clarifying person! I really appreciate it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I remember correctly, TCP load balancing was not working when using port forwarding. Try to run the script from a container inside k8s instead of doing port forwarding.

Comment: I've updated the question with the steps I did to validate the direction you've pointed me to!